# Limit to compare growth of function

Tags: limits

I wanted to compare growth of two functions

$F_1:n^{\,\lg\,\lg n}$

$F_2:(3/2)^n$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\lg\lg n}}{(3/2)^n}$

After differentiating it $\lg \, \lg n$ times I get

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\lg\lg n)!}{(\lg(3/2))^{\lg\lg n}(3/2)^n}$

How do I proceed forward?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$y=\frac{F_1}{F_2}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{-n} n^{\log (\log (n))}$$ and take logarithms
$$\log(y)={\log (\log (n))}\times \log(n)-n\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=n\left({\log (\log (n))}\times \frac {\log(n)}n-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \right)$$ When $n \to \infty$, since $\frac {\log(n)}n \to0 $, you have 
$$\log(y) \sim -n \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \to -\infty\implies y=e^{\log(n)} \to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

$(\ln \ln n) (\ln n) - n \ln (3/2)=n[\frac {(\ln \ln n) (\ln n)} n -  \ln (3/2)] \to -\infty$ because $\frac {(\ln \ln n) (\ln n)} n \to 0$. [ Use L'Hopital's Rule for this]. Taking exponential we get $e^{(\ln \ln n) (\ln n) } /(3/2)^{n} \to 0$. This is same as $\frac {n^{\ln  \ln n}} {(3/2)^{n}} \to 0$

Comment: Same time, same answer !